# conditional rendering certain form components based on user input react native + Formik

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-native, conditional-statements, formik

I am trying to make a form for users to fill out their billing info on checkout. To do so I am using Formik. I have the country and state fields as pickers, and want the states to change dynamically based on the country input. How can I implement this? If the user chooses canada I want provinces to show up, and if they input USA I want the states to show up. I'm not sure if I can use conditional rendering here because it is within the props of formik and should change dynamically:

```
      <Formik
        initialValues={{
          first_name: '',
          last_name: '',
          address_1: '',
          address_2: '',
          city: '',
          state: '',
          postcode: '',
          country: '',
          email: 'john.doe@example.com',
          phone: '647-274-8068',
        }}
        // Form submission action
        onSubmit={async (values) => {
          addData(values);
        }}>
        {(props) => (
          <KeyboardAvoidingView
            behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : null}
            style={{flex: 1}}>
            <ScrollView style={styles.inner}>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="first name"
                onChangeText={props.handleChange('first_name')}
                value={props.values.first_name}
              />
              <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="last name"
                onChangeText={props.handleChange('last_name')}
                value={props.values.last_name}
              />
              <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="Street Address"
                onChangeText={props.handleChange('address_1')}
                value={props.values.address_1}
              />
              <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="Unit"
                onChangeText={props.handleChange('address_2')}
                value={props.values.address_2}
              />
              <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="City"
                onChangeText={props.handleChange('city')}
                value={props.values.city}
              />
              <Picker
                selectedValue={props.values.country}
                onValueChange={props.handleChange('country')}>
                <Picker.Item label="Canada" value="CA" />
                <Picker.Item label="USA" value="US" />
              </Picker>
              <Picker
                selectedValue={props.values.state}
                onValueChange={props.handleChange('state')}>
                <Picker.Item label="Alberta" value="AB" />
                <Picker.Item label="British Columbia" value="BC" />
                <Picker.Item label="Manitoba" value="MB" />
                <Picker.Item label="New Brunswick" value="NB" />
                <Picker.Item label="Newfoundland and Labrador" value="NL" />
                <Picker.Item label="Northwest Territories" value="NT" />
                <Picker.Item label="Nova Scotia" value="NS" />
                <Picker.Item label="Nunavut" value="NU" />
                <Picker.Item label="Ontario" value="ON" />
                <Picker.Item label="Prince Edward Island" value="PE" />
                <Picker.Item label="Quebec" value="QC" />
                <Picker.Item label="Saskatchewan" value="SK" />
                <Picker.Item label="Yukon" value="YT" />
              </Picker>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="Postal Code"
                onChangeText={props.handleChange('postcode')}
                value={props.values.postcode}
              />
              <Button
                title="place order"
                color="maroon"
                onPress={props.handleSubmit}
              />
            </ScrollView>
          </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        )}
      </Formik>
```

The above code is in my return statement

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is maintain two states as `selected_country` and `provinces`. `selected_country` will be of type string and `provinces` will be of type array. On selecting the county you need to perform some CRUD operation where you need to fetch the data or the names of the provinces that are in the selected country. Once you do that set the state of `selected_country` and `provinces`. This will again change if the user selected another country. This is how you can dynamically provide the provinces based on the selected country.

Comment: Thanks I will try this. I just stored the provinces in 2 different arrays, 1 for US and 1 for Canada. I want to call the appropriate array by using  ``` {provinces.map((item, index) => {return <Picker.Item label={item} value={item} />;})}``` But replace "provinces" with either "US" or "CA". Can you advise me on how to get these values?